# Why wont Ubuntu boot unless I remove my windows hard disk?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my second hard drive. In the bios on my computer I can chose what disk I can boot from and I want my windows and ubuntu OS to be independent OS with no common interface ( like group boot loader ). So I removed my hard drive with the windows OS from my PC and installed Ubuntu on the second hard drive. I was hoping by removing the windows HD that this group boot loader would install quietly and don´t care about windows. My Ubuntu works fine until I put the windows HD back in, then it will not boot. If I remove the windows HD again then Ubuntu boots.
In other words Ubuntu refuse to boot when I have also windows HD installed.
Even if I chose the Ubuntu to be the first drive in my bios.
There is no problem to boot windows.
Here is a link about my boot file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23654044/
I just want Ubuntu to leave my windows disk alone.
Sorry for my English.
Sorr

Comment: You have a newer UEFI system, but both Windows & Ubuntu installed in BIOS/MBR boot mode. But you show some left over gpt data on sda. Normally that does not interfere with Windows, as it is Windows own partition tools incorrectly converting gpt to MBR. You should remove gpt data from sda with fixparts. http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/ But not sure if your issue or not. Are you changing drive order that drives are plugged into SATA ports. Best to have Windows in SATA0, first port and Ubuntu in SATA1. Boot-Repair mentions Secure boot, make sure it is off.

Comment: Can you get to the grub prompt with both disks present?  If so, try checking (type c and try ls to see which disk is which)/editing (type e) the disk references (change hd0 to hd1 etc.) and booting.  Make permanent with sudo update-grub if you successfully boot Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Since you removed the Windows disk when you installed Ubuntu, the GRUB boot loader has been set up to boot from disk #1 (the only disk in the machine at the time).

Now, you have plugged both disks (Windows is #1, Linux is #2), and told the BIOS to boot the Linux disk. The BIOS start GRUB, GRUB looks for its files on disk #1, except they are now on disk #2. GRUB does not find the files, and fails.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to prioritize your disk accordingly. In my case I would need to make sure that I activate Ubuntu disk as my first Disk so it boot from there. If your Windows Disk has been active in your BIOS as DISK 1 may be after plugging it back would move Ubuntu to second place Disk therefore won't boot from there. I do not know what BIOS you have or how it works but this is how mine works. Be ready to have Ubuntu creating a boot loader in your Ubuntu Disk. It (Grub2)will do it automatically. That way you can always start from there and choose from there and skip BIOS. This will not modify your Windows Boot loader.